# how can i send personalized email to each user

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, exchangewebservices

This is my code:

```
if((recipientsBcc != null) && (recipientsBcc.length > 0)){          
addressBcc = new InternetAddress[recipientsBcc.length];
}

MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Receipt_From));
if(addressBcc != null){
for (int i = 0; i < recipientsBcc.length; i++) {
addressBcc[i] = new InternetAddress(recipientsBcc[i]);
}
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, addressBcc); 
Transport.send(message);
```

This will send mail to all users but i want to send personalized mail to each users at once and user has to see their own mail Id in recipient To.

Comment: and you have no idea on how to implement a for-loop in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to call the send method in the for loop.

```
if((recipientsBcc != null) && (recipientsBcc.length > 0))
{          
    addressBcc = new InternetAddress[recipientsBcc.length];
}
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Receipt_From));
if(addressBcc != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < recipientsBcc.length; i++) 
    {
        addressBcc[i] = new InternetAddress(recipientsBcc[i]);
        //This will send indiviaual emails.
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressBcc); 
        Transport.send(message);
    }
}
```